# How to check if a certain Pattern is in a string representation of an xml response?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code:

```
        Matcher title = Pattern.compile("<Title> (.+?)</Title>").matcher(epg); // for new dongle setup
//Matcher title = Pattern.compile("<Title> \"(.+?)\"</Title>").matcher(epg); // for old dongle setup
```

I have an xml response in string form that I'm looking to parse into the matcher object. The title will either be in this format:

```
<Title> "The Ellen DeGeneres Show"</Title>
```

or this format:

```
<Title> The Ellen DeGeneres Show</Title>
```

So essentially its a difference of quotation marks. How can I make my if statement to check for this before I choose which method to use. To sum up

```
if(pattern is with quotation marks){
Matcher title = Pattern.compile("<Title> \"(.+?)\"</Title>").matcher(epg);
} else if (pattern is without quotation marks){
Matcher title = Pattern.compile("<Title> (.+?)</Title>").matcher(epg)
}
```

I can't wrap my head around what to put in the if statements.

Comment: Why don't you make quotation marks optional in your regex? - no if needed

Comment: @UrosK Thank you! I added the question mark after the quotation marks and it works! I'm not familiar with Regex and I had to send in a new build ASAP (didn't have time to go through documentation) which is why I asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to answer yourself and accept the answer.

Comment: it's generally unsafe to use regex on xml. Use an xml parser and xpath, for instance

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy It's actually in string form, I edited the question, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JvalantDave doesn't matter what the form is. Regex on xml is an unsafe thing to do. Use an xml parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon @UrosK's suggestion, I looked up how to make characters optional in Regex. Turns out I have to add a question mark after the character that I would like to be optional. Now my statement looks like the following:

```
Matcher title = Pattern.compile("<Title> \"?(.+?)\"?</Title>").matcher(epg);
```

Comment: This is correct. +1 and also kudos also to Uros. :-)

Comment: This will also match unbalanced quotes, e.g., `<Title>"oops</Title>`. Also note that you have a space after the opening tag. Finally you may want to use `[^<]+` (match to the next opening pointy brace) instead of `.+?` (match everything) in the capture, depending on whether there can be more XML elements within the `<Title>` or after it.

Comment: Sure, but given the use case described, one can spare the extra work. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try

```
Matcher title = Pattern.compile("<Title>\\s*\"?([^\"]*)\"?</Title>").matcher(epg);
```

to allow for any number of spaces (\s) after the opening tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the regex for the two respective situations, and then use the `|` operator to join them up.

The following is my code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexOptionalQuotationMarks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = {
                "<Title> \"The Ellen DeGeneres Show\"</Title>"
                , "<Title> The Ellen DeGeneres Show</Title>"
        };

        String regexWithoutQm   = "<Title>\\s*\\w[^<]*</Title>";
        String regexWithQm      = "<Title>\\s*\"[^\"<]*\"\\s*</Title>";
        String regexBoth        = regexWithoutQm + "|" + regexWithQm;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexBoth);
        for (String s : input) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            System.out.format("matching input %s ... %b%n", s, m.find());
        }

    }

}
```

The output of this program was this:

```
matching input <Title> "The Ellen DeGeneres Show"</Title> ... true
matching input <Title> The Ellen DeGeneres Show</Title> ... true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    String xml = "<root><Title>test</Title></root>";
    Document dDoc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//Title", dDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println(node.getTextContent());

    final String text = node.getTextContent().trim();
    if(text.matches("^\\\".*\\\"$")){
        // Between double quotes
    }
    else{
        // No quotes
    }
```

Find "Title" node first and then check its content for pattern